# Run an Asterisk command ON Asterisk startup

Tags: linux, asterisk

I'd like to run an asterisk command once asterisk is up and running and loaded all modules.

Any advice please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) When asterisk fully booted it issue FULLY BOOTED event via AMI.

2) You have special CLI command for that,which will wait if not compleated boot.

```
[pro-sip.net]# asterisk -rx "core waitfullybooted"
Asterisk has fully booted.
```

Comment: Thanks - just what I needed :)